An index that covers both an ARRAY column and sorting by another column in postgres?
Let's say I have a table with an array column and an integer column:
CREATE TABLE records(
   score INTEGER;
   features INTEGER[];
);

Now I want to make queries that extract rows that have at least one of the requested features, and then I also want to order them by score.
So something like this:
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE $1 && features 
ORDER BY score;

But I have no idea what kind of index could be used to speed up this query. I have a BTREE on score and GIN on features, but I don't think the index on score is going to be used.
Another peculiarity is that records is actually a denormalised materialised view, and features are composed by inner joining with other tables (basically each feature is a row in features table and then there's another table that marks a record as having the specified feature). If the queries on the materialised view can't be reasonably sped up, then maybe I should get rid of it and just query a basic view.
Bonus question: what if there are also other INTEGER array columns which also need to be checked for containing a certain value? How are such queries usually handled?

"maybe I should get rid of it and just query a basic view" probably. Seems only useful if you want the whole array as a blob, not if you want to search it. The base table could be indexed (feature, score) then you can do a join on each feature you want. Would that work?

I might have gotten you wrong, but the base table doesn't have features. I have to do 3 joins to extract all the features of the record.

OK then maybe the materialized view should just show all the rows instead of aggregating into arrays. Please give a [mcve] with all relevant tables and the view definition.

Sorting is generally quite fast compared to reading the data so it can be sorted, so this probably does not need to be optimized.  That might be different if you had a LIMIT clause, however.  In that case using an index to satisfy the ORDER BY can enable early stopping.
No built in index type will do what you want.  You can use the RUM extension, however.
create index on records using rum ( features rum_anyarray_addon_ops, score) 
   with (attach = 'score', to='features');

It does require you to write the query in a peculiar way:
SELECT *
FROM records
WHERE ARRAY[1,5,9,23,56,99] && features
ORDER BY score <=> -1 LIMIT 5;

Where the arbitrary constant -1 is assumed to be less than or equal to the smallest possible value of score.

I actually do need a LIMIT and OFFSET since I want paging for records, thanks for bringing this up. I'll look into that extension but maybe I'm just overcomplicating things and I don't need a materialised view and multicolumn indexes at all. Especially considering there could be more conditions for the search so that the WHERE clause would get more complex.

@DiplomateProgrammer: Why don't you just show your real situation in the question?
